# How to load the templates from web service in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-services

I have a different templates in my database. As admin, I can set which template will show for users.

Is it possible to load the template from db through APIs in Angular4?

Comment: yeah it is possible.. Read about [Angular Dynamic Component Loading](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: you can use innerHTML to show the html elements